# Запрет добавления в базу при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос такой. На странице есть форма. В нее мы вбиваем данные. После этого жмем отправить. Форма обрабатывается самой страницей. Данные попадают в базу. Все огонь. Но если после этого обновить страницу, то данные отправляются в базу повторно. Вопрос, как этого избежать? 
Второй вопрос - можно ли сделать unset глобального массива $_POST?

Comment: Просто unset'ни переменную с именем кнопки submit после обновления данных.
А перед скриптом добавления данных в БД, делай проверку на существование этой переменной (с именем кнопки submit).

Теперь если просто обновить страницу (не нажимая на кнопку "Отправить"), данные никуда не полетят, то бишь не добавятся в БД.

Comment: Неа, не проходит. Однозначно нет.
Идет после добавления в базу unset параметра кнопки. Обновляем страницу и але оп все опять добавляется. Такое ощущение, что unset не сносит глобальные массивы.

Comment: Разумеется не сносит.  
А вот элемент массива - запросто.

Comment: @TheDoctor 
Объясните плз как:
Идет:
if ($_POST['send'] == "Отправить")
{
тут идет инсерт.
}
unset ($_POST['send']);
Перезагружаем страницу и все проходит в базу. 
Я так понимаю, что $_POST - глобальный. Поэтому, когда мы делаем unset - мы сносим его только в рамках данного скрипта при этой обработке. Когда страница перезагружается, то из глобального массива вновь получаются данные на отправку.

Comment: Работает `unset` и на глобальной переменной.  
Другое интересно - это не будет работать, массив, как ты правильно заметил, уже новый генерируется.  
Юзай лучше токен, см. ответ ниже (или выше, смотря как сортировать :)).

Comment: @TheDoctor Мне тут один "искусственный интеллект" подсказал коварный план. В общем, делать надо так. 

Файл форма -> Файл обработчик -> редирект по истории на предыдущую страницу. 
Все.

Плюсы по сравнению с генерацией md5(time()) в том, что нет нужды создавать доп поле в базе, и не надо передавать + 1 значение. Легче база, меньше нагрузка. 

Похоже, об этом писал @BOPOH, но я его не понял. 
Токен хорош. Рассмотрю и его вариант использования.

Comment: Так мы подумали раз у тебя такой вопрос, значит ты в любом случае через AJAX работаешь.  
Иначе вопрос бы не возник.  
А если AJAX, то перезагружать страницу как-то... не вебдванольно =)  
Можно было бы тогда вообще не парится про AJAX - прямая ссылка и вообще нет проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генерируйте уникальный `string`, например, выражением `md5(time())`. Результат типа `5027a4d8064c9419ef1d39faf725ae35df331946` сажайте в форму, наряду с другими элементами, в виде:

```
<input type='hidden' name='check' value='5027a4d8064c9419ef1d39faf725ae35df331946' />
```

Затем, при обновлении страницы, проверяйте `SELECT`-ом наличие строки в таблице с такой записью. Если уже есть, то не делайте `INSERT` еще раз.

Comment: Плюс - токен может защитить от CSRF, двух и более зайцев убьёшь :)

Comment: Дополнительно можно использовать [Post/Redirect/Get](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), чтобы пользователю не показывались предложения повторно отправить данные

Answer (score 0):

В общем, задача решилась на удивление просто:
Надо было вынести обработчик формы в отдельный файл, а после его срабатывания вернуть пользователя редиректом.
Итого:
Форма -> Обработчик (в нем header( "location:".$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]);) -> попадаем на исходную страницу.

Вторая часть вопроса решена, совместными усилиями с [@TheDoctor](/users/31688/thedoctor). Полный Unset глобавльного массива не возможен.

Comment: Чяловек, `Referer` далеко не всегда есть, помни об этом!

Comment: Даже Википедия об этом [предупреждает][1].


  [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Чет я не понял, зачем такой долгий путь Форма - Обработчик - Форма, если просто данные в БД заносятся. Тогда, действительно, проще и удобней для пользователя Ajax будет.

И про Referer соглашусь, не факт, что у всех сработает.